# Symfony voter: how do I check a user's role?

Tags: php, symfony

I have Posts that are owned by a specific user. I've created a voter to check if the user owns the Post, but I also want admins (ie, ROLE_ADMIN and above) to be able to access all Posts.

I've followed the instructions (and nearly copied the code) on the [How to Use Voters to Check User Permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) cookbook entry. Now I'm wondering how I do the check. Ideas:

1. Pass another service into the Voter...not sure which one.
2. Do something with the `vote` method.
3. Don't do the check in the voter, but do it inside the controller (ie, don't call the voter check if they're an admin).

Comment: I appreciate this is an old question, but I stumbled across it asking the question myself. For Symfony 3 and up you can inject the [AccessDecisionManager](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/voters.html#checking-for-roles-inside-a-voter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with. Basically overrode the parent `vote()` method, adding the check for roles within it. The role check concerns me a bit since it isn't using any of the built in method, but I'm not sure they're accessible and that it won't create a loop (since role checking uses a voter as well). I've tagged the parts that are custom.

Let me know if anything is a big no no.

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Security/Authorization/Voter/PostVoter.php

namespace AppBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\AbstractVoter;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

class PostVoter extends AbstractVoter
{
    const VIEW = 'view';
    const EDIT = 'edit';

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
    {
        if (!$object || !$this->supportsClass(get_class($object))) {
            return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        }

        // ----------------------------------
        // -- start – custom
        $user = $token->getUser();
        if ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
            if (in_array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', $user->getRoles())) {
                return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
        }
        // -- end – custom
        // ----------------------------------

        // abstain vote by default in case none of the attributes are supported
        $vote = self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;

        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if (!$this->supportsAttribute($attribute)) {
                continue;
            }

            // as soon as at least one attribute is supported, default is to deny access
            $vote = self::ACCESS_DENIED;

            if ($this->isGranted($attribute, $object, $token->getUser())) {
                // grant access as soon as at least one voter returns a positive response
                return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
        }

        return $vote;
    }

    // ----------------------------------
    // -- start – custom
    protected function isGranted($attribute, $post, $user = null)
    {
        switch($attribute) {
            case self::VIEW:
                if ($post->getIsActive()) {
                    return true;
                }
                break;

            // must be owned by the current user or the user must be a super admin
            case self::EDIT:
                // make sure there is a user object (i.e. that the user is logged in)
                if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
                    return false;
                }

                if ($user->getId() === $post->getOwner()->getId()) {
                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
    // -- end – custom
    // ----------------------------------

    protected function getSupportedAttributes()
    {
        return array(self::VIEW, self::EDIT);
    }

    protected function getSupportedClasses()
    {
        return array('AppBundle\Entity\Post');
    }

}
```

Comment: It is a big no no indeed: roles should be only checked by security system, not by getting them from the user (because of the hierarchy). See https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#hierarchical-roles for a reference